# How many searches can handled by Solr per second if index file is more than or equal to 2 GB?

Tags: solr, lucene.net

NopCommerce 2.30 is running on IIS 7.5 and Server has 16GB RAM with Dual Core processor.I want to implement Solr with Nop Commerce.
How many searches can handled by Solr per second if index file is more than or equal to 2 GB?

Comment: there are so many factors that can alter performances that a precise answer to your question is impossible. It will depend on your hardware (mainly IO systems), the nature of the indexed data, the type of queries that are performed, etc. The best advice I can give you is to test it yourself using a tool like JMeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend this presentation that will make it easy for you to find out your system capabilities.
http://www.lucidimagination.com/devzone/events/conferences/lucene-revolution-2012-presentations#Paddy_Mullen

It is described how to index Wikipedia as a Benchmark of Single Machine Performance Limit.
Also there is some information about this on the dataimporthandler wiki of solr.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Example:_Indexing_wikipedia

From my experience with solr I can say that I have a 10 GB index splitted in 9 cores and I do 2300 requests per minute and I have an average response time of 40 ms. This is on two  AMD Opteron 2.6 ghz processors.

Comment: Can the loading whole index of 6-7 GB into memory speedup the things?

Comment: Probably so depends on your specific workload: Generally speaking, Loading into RAM helps if you're disk bounded. Not so much if your current workload is CPU bounded.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should ask the expert who do it for nop commerce here: http://nopaccelerate.com/

Comment: thank you for providing me a link to our site.. http://wwww.nopaccelerate.com/ is our product for nopCommerce Solr integration. And Yes, with lot of research and deployment we now know lot of about Solr and nopCommere performance optimization, but still we're learning everyday.